# dos command to delete a folder except the named sub folders

Tags: dos

Assume I have a directory in your computer under C:/dir1

And inside "dir1" we have more directories   dir11, dir12, dir13,

And in each of the above directories we have more like below 
dir11- dir111, dir112 dir113
dir1-dir121, dir122, dir123
dir13 - dir132,dir132,dir133

Now I need to find a command or a small script, which can delete everything under dir1 except couple of directories say dir122 and dir132.

Can you find something using DOS commands ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  And are you really looking for DOS commands, or is this for a Windows batch file?

Check http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist for a list of questions to ask yourself before posting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dir filespec /b >tmp.bat` to list the file names in a text file called tmp.bat. Then edit that file to add `del` before each file name you want to delete. You can remove the file names you want to keep from the batch file and then do a "change all" to add `del` to each line. When it is edited properly, execute the batch file.

Alternatively, you could write a quick program under vb.net to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Using the given examples: this should `echo` all the rd commands for the other folders.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (' dir "c:\dir1" /b /s /ad ^| findstr /v /i "dir122 dir132" ') do echo rd /s /q "%%a"
```